# Problem with distinguishing filenames and checking for info in the filename

Tags: python-3.x

Having a problem in python where I need to check filenames. Is there any way to search for key words in filename for python?

For example:

john_bagels_t3.txt

gill_jones_t1.txt

haley_twice_t2.txt

I have txt files with different versions t1, t2, t3. How do I check if the filename has it and return which version it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python `os` APIs to get filename and run regex on filenames to find out required format.

For example:

```py
import os
import re

for file in os.listdir("/Users/my_user/Downloads"):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if m := re.match(r".*_(t\d).txt$", filename):
        print(f"Matched filename: {filename}")
        print(f"Version: {m.group(1)}")
```

If you place files under above directory, then output:

```
Matched filename: gill_jones_t1.txt
Version: t1
Matched filename: john_bagels_t3.txt
Version: t3
Matched filename: haley_twice_t2.txt
Version: t2
```